# How do I change a for loop into a while loop using certain conditions (dot location, window width)?

Tags: java

I am creating a dot race program and I need help changing a for loop into a while loop using certain conditions. Those conditions being the x coordinate of the dot and the width of the window. I want it so that no matter what width I choose to make the window, the program knows when the dot finishes.

Here is the code:

```
    createWindows();
                // rise in steps of 10 pixels, cruise in steps of 5 pixels
        final int hStep = 28;
        final int vStep = 0;

        Dot connectMe = new Dot(100, 270, 70, Color.yellow, dotCourse);
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            connectMe.moveDot(connectMe.getX(), connectMe.getY()-vStep);  // Move up by vStep
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<30;i++)
        {
            connectMe.moveDot(connectMe.getX() + hStep, connectMe.getY());  // Move right by hStep
            Thread.sleep(200);

        boolean finish = (GWINDOW_WIDTH-60) <= connectMe.getX();
            if (finish) {
        }
            System.out.println("Did the dot finish? : " + finish); 
        }

}
```

Comment: `int i=0;
while(i<20){
//the other stuff
i++;
}`

Comment: And what have you tried?  Do you know how to make a `while` loop?  Hint: When a `for` loop does this: `for (X; Y; Z) { }` then an equivalent `while` loop is this: `X; while (Y) { Z; }`

Comment: This is quite simple. The natural language algorithm is: "As long as the window width is larger than the dot's x position, move the dot one step." Now you write this exact algorithm with Java syntax, it translates almost word by word. If you do not know how a while loop is written, look at the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). If you have trouble with you implementation, post it and ask for more help.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I entered 'int i=0;
   while(i<30)
   {
                connectMe.moveDot(connectMe.getX() + hStep, connectMe.getY());  // Move right by hStep
                Thread.sleep(200);
                i++;'  and when I try to change the width, the dot goes beyond the width or falls short of the edge of the window

Comment: Yes, and that is pretty much the same as you showed above, just replacing the for by a while loop. But it still does a fixed 30 steps, and not "as long as the dot has not reached the end". You need to change the stop condition of your while loop, and you even have the correct condition in your code above already.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you always move the dot the same amount: 30 (loops) x 28 (pixels). No matter how wide the window is or how far each step, you always move 860 pixels.

So you have to adapt your step width or your step count. Changing the width would change the speed, so that's probably not what you want. Instead, you have to take more or less steps, until the dot reaches. As I said in the comment, the natural language algorithm translates exactly to java:

```
/* As long as           */ while (
/* the window width     */   GWINDOW_WIDTH-60
/* is larger than       */   >
/* the dot's x position */   connectMe.getX()) {
/* move the dot         */     connectMe.moveDot(connectMe.getX() + hStep, connectMe.getY());
/* one step.            */     Thread.sleep(200);
/*                      */ }
```